# Memory monitor in Java using Swing and AWT

Tags: java

I need code for the memory monitor using Swing which displays the memory pool contents such as code cache, eden space, survivor space, perm gen, temred gen, tenured space and plots memory usage graph.

Comment: Cool! What have you written so far?

Comment: It's called "Swing" and not "Swings".

Comment: In his defense, we were promised a healthy component marketplace which would have widgets just like that...

Comment: @Thilo: by whom? Also: this is not that marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ManagementFactory` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) to get the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Runtime` class to get basic memory information:

```
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```